# Read Only domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

What is the procedure of making a domain controler Read only in windows server 2008?

Answer (score 5):

When you go through dcpromo wizard there is an option to install as read only. If you are asking about converting a normal DC to RODC, you can't. Need to take the DC to regular member server, and then re-run dcpromo and choose rodc I believe.

[image]

Comment: If you can add more detail, it would be an even better answer :-)

Comment: @Randolph - there's not much more detail to add, that's pretty much what it is. When you run `dcpromo` it's a tickbox you check...

Comment: I was going for a screen capture. I did vote this one up.

Comment: Here : http://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/rodc_installation.png

Comment: @mangloide put the screenshot into your post for you so the link doesn't go stale.

Comment: Now I'm happy! Thanks for the image. Now can Zypher delete all these comments? :-)